Unable to extract some properties from Maven settings.xml using either xmllint or xmlstarlet
I have a Maven settings file at ~/.m2/settings.xml.  I need to write some scripting that extracts the username and password from one of the server entries.
I've tried using both "xmllint" and "xmlstarlet" using what I believe are the correct (different) command-line parameters for both of those.  The result for both is just an empty string. There is no error, it just prints nothing.
This is an excerpt of ~/.m2/settings.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    ...
    --><!--
     | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
    ...
     |-->
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

      <servers>
        <server>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <username>...</username>
                    <password>...</password>
        </server>
    ...

This is working fine with Maven.
For xmllint, I'm trying the following:
xmllint --xpath 'string(//server[id="central"]/username/text())' ~/.m2/settings.xml 

For xmlstarlet, it is this:
xmlstarlet sel -T -R -D -t -v "//settings/servers/server[id='central']/username/text()" ~/.m2/settings.xml

Those are slightly semantically different, but I've tried several variations. All of these just print an empty string.

The document uses XML namespaces, you need to specify those. The simplest approach is to use xmlstarlet’s _ placeholder for the default namespace:
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/_:settings/_:servers/_:server[_:id="central"]/_:username' ~/.m2/settings.xml

